# how to make a picture become interactive with buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

*[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmJv1.jpg
Hi everyone, I would like to thank any help in advance.
I'm quite new to this whole coding world, so i have been given a project to do. I have already set up the HTML file to how I want it to look and etc.... The only problem I'm currently having is, I'm not sure how to use javascript to make the buttons work and store the information. Would anyone share some light on how to get the beds to become interactive? I guess once I can get the beds to be interactive with the buttons I can somewhat play around with the rest and see how I get on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title> Ward Beds </title>

    <style>

    body{ border: groove 4px; } 
    
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="LIGHTSKYBLUE">

    <form
          <div
   </div>
        <p>

        </p>
             <img id="Bed1" src="bedleftempty.gif" /> <img id="Bed5" src="BedREmpty.gif" />
      
    <div
   </div>
             <img id="Bed2" src="bedleftempty.gif" /> <img id="Bed6" src="BedREmpty.gif" />

   <div
   </div>
             <img id="Bed3" src="bedleftempty.gif" /> <img id="Bed7" src="BedREmpty.gif" />

   <div
   </div>
            <img id="Bed4" src="bedleftempty.gif" /> <img id="Bed8" src="BedREmpty.gif" />
        <div
   </div>
        
   <center> 

       <input id="btnAdmit" type="button" value="Admit" 
               onclick="btnAdmit_OnClick()" > <input id="btnDischarge" type="button" value="Discharge"
                                           onclick="btnDischarge_OnClick()" />
    <div
   </div>
        <p>
            <input id="btnMale" type="button" value="Male"
                   onclick="btnMale_OnClick()" />
                   

            <div
   </div>
            <input id="btnFemale" type="button" value="Female"
                   onclick="btnFemale_OnClick()" />
            <div
   </div>
            <input id="btnUnknown" type="button" value="Unknown"
                   onclick="btnUnknown_OnClick()" />
            <div
   </div>
        </p>
    <p>
        <label>First Name</label> <input type="text" id="myText" value=" " /> <label>Last Name</label> <input type="text" id="myText" value=" " />
    </p>   
    <label> Location of Surgery</label>
    <div
     </div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="LeftArm" value="LeftLeg"> LeftArm<br> />
    <div
     </div>
             <input type="checkbox" name="RightArm" value="RightLeg" > RightArm<br> />
        <div
     </div>
             <input type="checkbox" name="LeftLeg" value="LeftLeg"> LeftLeg<br> />
    <div
     </div>
             <input type="checkbox" name="RightLeg" value="RightLeg"> RightLeg<br> />
        <div
     </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Unknown" value="Unknown"> Unknown<br> />
        <div
     </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Head" value="Head"> Head<br> />
        <div
     </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Chest" value="Chest"> Chest<br> />
        <div
     </div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Abdomen" value="Abdomen"> Abdomen<br> />
        <div
     </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
        
    
</body>
</html>

<script language="javascript">
```

Comment: center tag is deprecated and you shouldn't use it and there is no such tag as a right tag, plus you have invalid html (you have not closed some divs properly).  You probably want to read something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data and figure out what you want to do with the data.  At the moment this question is very broad and therefore off topic for SO

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!!! much appreciated. all i'm trying to create is something that will allow me to manage 8 beds within a hospital ward. where i will click male or female, the location of surgery and first and last name and then place the information onto a bed. so when i click on the bed i can edit name and last name or the place of surgery. and once i click discharge the information is removed from the bed. sorry if its a bit confusing on how im explaining stuff.

Comment: Do you want to fill the beds with the patients info?

Comment: Yeah, the information needs to be stored when the patient is admitted and when the patient is discharged the information needs to go.

Answer (score 1):

Well my advise advice is to start with simple HTML tutorials.
Because there is a lot of invalid html and some invalid css.

```js
function GetId(id) { return document.getElementById(id) }

// Store information for eatch bed in an array
var beds = [],
  // Stores amount of max beds
    maxBeds = 8,
    // Get beds paragraph
    htmlBeds = GetId("beds");

// Loops the amount of maxBeds by increasing i eatch time
for (let i = 0; i < maxBeds; i++) {
 // Add an empy bed.
  htmlBeds.innerHTML += '<img id="Bed'+(i+1)+'" src="http://mtdef.com/Lib/Img/StackOverflow/bed.png" onclick="bed_Onclick('+i+')"> ';
  if (i % 2) htmlBeds.innerHTML += '<br>';
}

//functions you request from the html
function btnAdmit_OnClick() {
  let gender, fullName, surgeryLocation = "";
  if (GetId('btnMale').checked) gender = "Male";
  if (GetId('btnFemale').checked) gender = "Female";
  if (GetId('btnUnknown').checked) gender = "Unknown";
  
  fullName = GetId('FirstName').value + " " + GetId('LastName').value;
  
  // Loop 8 times over the Location of Surgery by increasing i eatch time.
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let LoS = GetId("LoS"+i); 
    if (LoS.checked) surgeryLocation += LoS.value + " ";
  }
  
  //push patient object to array
  beds.push({
    gender:gender,
    fullName:fullName,
    surgeryLocation:surgeryLocation
  });
}

//removes last added patient
function btnDischarge_OnClick() {
  beds.splice(-1,1);
}

//shows patients stats
function bed_Onclick(bedId) {
  if (beds[bedId] === undefined) console.log("bed: " + (bedId+1) + 
  "\nis empty");
  else console.log("bed: " + (bedId+1) + 
    "\ngender: " + beds[bedId].gender + 
    "\nfull name: " + beds[bedId].fullName + 
    "\nlocation of surgery: " + beds[bedId].surgeryLocation
  );
}
```

```css
    body { 
      background-color: lightblue;
      border: groove 4px;
    }
```

```html
<center> 
  <!-- Get filled by JavaScript -->
  <p id=beds></p>
  <input id="btnAdmit" type="button" value="Admit" onclick="btnAdmit_OnClick()" >
  <input id="btnDischarge" type="button" value="Discharge" onclick="btnDischarge_OnClick()" >
  <p>
    <input id="btnMale" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">
    <label for="btnMale">Male</label><br>
    <input id="btnFemale" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">
    <label for="btnFemale">Female</label><br>
    <input id="btnUnknown" type="radio" name="gender" value="Unknown" checked="checked">
    <label for="btnUnknown">Unknown</label><br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>First Name</label> 
    <input type="text" id="FirstName" value="John"> <br>
    <label>Last Name</label> 
    <input type="text" id="LastName" value="Doe">
  </p>   
  <label> Location of Surgery</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS0" value="LeftArm"> LeftArm<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS1" value="RightArm" > RightArm<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS2" value="LeftLeg"> LeftLeg<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS3" value="RightLeg"> RightLeg<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS4" value="Unknown"> Unknown<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS5" value="Head"> Head<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS6" value="Chest"> Chest<br> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="LoS7" value="Abdomen"> Abdomen<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</center>
```

I hope that the comments are enough for you

Comment: unfortunately i don't, i'm just trying to take baby steps to get this thing to function. i've only been doing coding for 3 weeks and this project needs to be handed in 2 weeks from now. so i'm currently stressing to be honest.

Comment: @Chris can you accept the answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

one problem that might be causing you to not having stuff to work is that, in the example code you gave, you haven`t close the starting div tags and a couple over tags properly.
you have put ... that should help but for the button it seems that you have done it right but in your js file or in the script tag you just put

```
Female_OnClick() {  
    what you want it to do   
}
```

try closing all the tags properly, and try that javascript thing aswell and if it still doesnt work tell me and i may be able to help...

Comment: If you want to test that the button works, just add an id to one of the <p> e.g. <p id="testBtn"> and in the javascript, inside that button function put 
document.getElementById("testBtn").innerHTML = "Hello World";

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!!! much appreciated. all i'm trying to create is something that will allow me to manage 8 beds within a hospital ward. where i will click male or female, the location of surgery and first and last name and then place the information onto a bed. so when i click on the bed i can edit name and last name or the place of surgery. and once i click discharge the information is removed from the bed. sorry if its a bit confusing on how im explaining stuff.

Comment: Thats fine, I will quickly write something up to help you make this.

Comment: i've just updated to the whole code to the full thing. what's stopping me from moving foward is just making the beds interactive with the buttons. I have no idea on how to get this working.